# Function token_get_all not showing any tokens

Tags: php

I've got this simple code to test the output of token_get_all...

```
$arr = token_get_all("<?php $array=array(1,2,3); foreach($array as $key => $value) print($value); ?>");

print("<pre>");
print_r($arr);
print("</pre>");
```

But what ends up being displayed is this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 372
        [1] =>  1
    )

[1] => =
[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 362
        [1] => array
        [2] => 1
    )

[3] => (
[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 305
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 1
    )

[5] => ,
[6] => Array
    (
        [0] => 305
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 1
    )

[7] => ,
[8] => Array
    (
        [0] => 305
        [1] => 3
        [2] => 1
    )

[9] => )
[10] => ;
[11] => Array
    (
        [0] => 375
        [1] =>  
        [2] => 1
    )

[12] => Array
    (
        [0] => 322
        [1] => foreach
        [2] => 1
    )

[13] => (
[14] => Array
    (
        [0] => 375
        [1] =>  
        [2] => 1
    )

[15] => Array
    (
        [0] => 326
        [1] => as
        [2] => 1
    )

[16] => Array
    (
        [0] => 375
        [1] =>   
        [2] => 1
    )

[17] => Array
    (
        [0] => 360
        [1] => =>
        [2] => 1
    )

[18] => Array
    (
        [0] => 375
        [1] =>  
        [2] => 1
    )

[19] => )
[20] => Array
    (
        [0] => 375
        [1] =>  
        [2] => 1
    )

[21] => Array
    (
        [0] => 266
        [1] => print
        [2] => 1
    )

[22] => (
[23] => )
[24] => ;
[25] => Array
    (
        [0] => 375
        [1] =>  
        [2] => 1
    )

[26] => Array
    (
        [0] => 374
        [1] => ?>
        [2] => 1
    )

)
```

From everything I've read about token_get_all, I'd expect the [0] key of these arrays to be the token names.  What's going on with my code/server that I'm getting this instead?

I've also tried doing:

```
$arr = token_get_all(file_get_contents('someOtherValidPHPFile.php'));
```

And I get the same kind of result.

I'm using PHP version 5.4.19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tokens are defined as [*constants*](http://php.net/constants). E.g. the constant is named `T_ARRAY` and its value is `362`. You can compare the tokens to that constant:

```
if ($token[0] == T_ARRAY) ...
```

If you want to get the readable name, use [`token_name`](http://php.net/token_name).

Answer (score 2):

Yes the token type is on index `0`.

This is just a numeric value which identifies the token type. You can then compare them against the following list of token types: [List of Parser Tokens](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/tokens.php)

You can get the token name by using the [`token_name()`](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/function.token-name.php) function.